# Chartboost PostInstall Tracker

Tags: android, in-app, chartboost, post-install

Can someone explain to me how can i integrate Chartboost post install? 
Already tried this [post-install integration guide](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220265-Post-Install-Analytics#android) with my testing app (uploaded as alpha test) and with this reserved in-app purchases:

```
android.test.purchased
android.test.canceled
android.test.refunded
android.test.item_unavailable
```

When i try to run this code:

```
  public void ChartboostPI(View view) {
    trackInAppGooglePlayPurchaseEvent("Sample Title", "Sample description for product: android.test.canceled.", "0.99", "USD", "android.test.purchased", "inapp:"+this.getPackageName()+":android.test.canceled", "j");
  }
```

i'm getting:

```
  iap failure responce!!
```

P.S.:
Maybe there is some ways to test my own inapps, but i dont know how to specify this in in-app purchase code (I will be glad if someone will explain me how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer, cb developers posted example with release of 5.0.3

Here is example code:

```
public class GoogleIAPTracking extends Activity{

private static final String TAG = "com.chartboost.sdk.sample.cbtest.inappbilling";

private static final int INAPP_REQUEST_CODE = 10001;

//private static final String RELEASE_ITEM_SKU = "com.example.buttonclick";

private static final String TEST_ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";

private Button clickButton;

private Button buyButton;

private String ITEM_SKU;    

IabHelper mHelper;

Inventory inventory;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pit);
    Chartboost.onCreate(this);      
    Chartboost.setDelegate(delegate);
    buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton);   
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);
    ITEM_SKU = TEST_ITEM_SKU;
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = getResources().getString(R.string.base64EncodedPublicKey);

    /*Setting up Inapp billing purchase*/
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
    mHelper.startSetup(new 
    IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
    {
    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
      Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + 
    result);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "############# In-app Billing is set up ###############");
        Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");          
    }
    }
    });
}

public void buyClick(View view) {
     mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, INAPP_REQUEST_CODE,  mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

@Override
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
    Log.d(TAG,"###### onIabPurchaseFinished"+purchase +"#####"+ ITEM_SKU);
    if (result.isFailure()) {
         Runnable r = new Runnable() {              
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHelper.myconsume(GoogleIAPTracking.this.getPackageName(), "inapp:"+getPackageName()+":android.test.purchased");
        }
    };
    r.run(); 
    Log.d(TAG,"###### onIabPurchaseFinished Error ");
     return;
     }      
     else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    }
};

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener 
       = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
            Log.d(TAG,"###### onQueryInventoryFinished : " + inv);
              if (result.isFailure()) {
                  // Handle failure
                  } 
              else {
                  Log.d(TAG," ####### Its in the inventory consuming the item !!!!");
                  try{
                      // MIGHT THROW AN EXCEPTION IF Chartboost.onStart() is not called. 
                      Log.d(TAG,"########## Send it to Chartboost PIT ###########");
                         SkuDetails item = inv.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU);
                         Purchase purchase = inv.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
                         if(item !=null && purchase != null) {
                             String data =purchase.getOriginalJson();                            
                             String signature = TextUtils.isEmpty(purchase.getSignature()) ?"test":purchase.getSignature();
                             signature = TextUtils.isEmpty(signature) ?"test":signature;
                             if(item != null){
                                 CBAnalytics.trackInAppGooglePlayPurchaseEvent(item.getTitle(),
                                                                                           item.getDescription(),
                                                                                           item.getPrice(),
                                                                                           item.getCurrencyCode(),
                                                                                           purchase.getSku(),
                                                                                           data,
                                                                                           signature);
                             }
                         }
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                  mHelper.consumeAsync(inv.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU), mConsumeFinishedListener);
                }
        }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
    new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
     public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, 
           IabResult result) {
         Log.d(TAG,"###### onConsumeFinished");
        if (result.isSuccess()) {                
            Log.d(TAG,"###### onConsumeFinished sucess");
        } 
        buyButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
};


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }

};

/* The following methods reflect the buttons in our UI. */

public void onLoadButtonClick(View view) {
    String toastStr = "Loading Interstitial";
    Toast.makeText(this, toastStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_STARTUP);
}

public void onMoreButtonClick(View view) {
    String toastStr = "Loading More Apps";
    Toast.makeText(this, toastStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Chartboost.showMoreApps(CBLocation.LOCATION_GAME_SCREEN);
}

public void trackMiscRevenueGeneratingEventOfType(View view) {
    String toastStr = "Sending trackMiscRevenueGeneratingEventOfType to SDK ..";
    Toast.makeText(this, toastStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //pit.trackMiscRevenueGeneratingEvent(CBMiscRevenueGeneratingEventType.CBMiscRevenueGeneratingEventType1, 100, "USD", "HayDay");
}

public void trackCustomEventOfType(View view) {
    String toastStr = "Sending trackCustomEventOfType to SDK ..";
    Toast.makeText(this, toastStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //pit.trackCustomEventofType(CBCustomEventType.CBCustomEventType1, 2);
}

public void trackInGameScore(View view) {
    String toastStr = "Sending trackInGameScore to SDK ..";
    Toast.makeText(this, toastStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //pit.trackInGameScore(10);
}

public void trackPlayerCurrencyBalance(View view) {
    String toastStr = "Sending trackPlayerCurrencyBalance to SDK ..";
    Toast.makeText(this, toastStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //pit.trackPlayerCurrencyBalance(5, "USD");
}

/*Activity callback methods*/
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Chartboost.onStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,"### onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Chartboost.onStop(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (Chartboost.onBackPressed())
        return;
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Chartboost.onDestroy(this);
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}

 /**
  * Chartboost Delegate callbacks
  */
 private ChartboostDelegate delegate = new ChartboostDelegate() {

 };
}
```